# Read password in Scala in a console-agnostic way

Tags: scala, io, console

I have an easy task to accomplish: read a password from a command line prompt without exposing it. I know that there is `java.io.Console.readPassword`, however, there are times when you cannot access console as if you are running your app from an IDE (such as IntelliJ).

I stumbled upon this [Password Masking in the Java Programming Language](http://www.cse.chalmers.se/edu/year/2017/course/TDA602/Eraserlab/pwdmasking.html) tutorial, which looks nice, but I fail to implement it in Scala. So far my solution is:

```
class EraserThread() extends Runnable {

  private var stop = false

  override def run(): Unit = {
    stop = true
    while ( stop ) {
      System.out.print("\010*")
      try
        Thread.sleep(1)
      catch {
        case ie: InterruptedException =>
          ie.printStackTrace()
      }
    }
  }

  def stopMasking(): Unit = {
    this.stop = false
  }
}

val et = new EraserThread()
val mask = new Thread(et)
mask.start()

val password = StdIn.readLine("Password: ")

et.stopMasking()
```

When I start this snippet I get a continuos printing of asterisks on new lines. E.g.:

```
*
*
*
*
```

Is there any specific in Scala why this is not working? Or is there any better way to do this in Scala in general?

Comment: The notion that a separate thread would be running to try to overwrite echoed characters using ASCII backspace strikes me as a little odd, and really not console agnostic at all. The idea is to read the character but not to echo it in the first place. And, if you must echo something, you want to be careful about revealing the *length* of the password. So, maybe echo a random number of stars for each keypress.

Comment: Also, the way you use it, you might want to change `stop` to `keep_running` and see [Key Listener](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html)s.

Comment: @SinanÜnür just not echoenig input can work completely well. But I have not seen any solutions like this neither